# u-boot execute FIT image at a different location than load address

Tags: linux, u-boot

Hi I have a FIT image with u-boot headers wrapped (used mkimage to wrap the eload), how do I specify a different execution address for FIT image excluding the header length after u-boot load it into memory? Or is there command in u-boot to remove a fixed offset content then load the rest to memory?

It will stall the boot sequence since u-boot find the header instead of kernel/fdt image at the original execution address.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you clarify what you want the end result to be here?  We have load and entry properties for each part, but it also sounds like perhaps what you're really asking about is how to have the image contents not be moved around in memory again and executed in place.

Comment: Hi Tom, in my case, there're couple of u-boot headers containing FIT components' version information such as kernel, ramdisk etc. wrapped around the FIT image,  I'd like u-boot to skip those headers (since they are only useful for recording purpose, not for loading image purpose) during loading process. Is there a way to tell u-boot to skip, say the first 128KB and load the FIT image from its 129KB?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand why you're trying to do what you're doing, sorry.  You have 1 FIT image that contains a kernel, initrd, fdt (and a configuration that uses all of it I assume), yes?  And you're trying to optimize the boot process to be as quick as possible?